# How to get Session from Next-Auth in API Route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, next-auth

when I print my session from next auth in a component like this I can see all of its data.

```
const session = useSession();

// ...
<p>{JSON.stringify(session)}</p>
```

I need to access the session's content in one of my Endpoints, and when I run it, it returns null (in the network tab) in the response, even though I can see that the same exact component is printing it on the screen. (It should not return null because I'm logged in!)

I've tried this approach:

**`app/api/entries/route.js`**:

```
    export async function GET(req) { try { const session = await getSession({ req }); return  NextResponse.json(session); } catch (error) { throw new Error("Something went wrong."); } }
```

I've checked this GitHub issue where someone is encountering a similar bug, but the code that fixed it is what I have implemented. **[GitHub Issue](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/3386)**

Comment: Checkout https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#getsession.

Comment: thats client side though

Comment: This is what I wanted you to realize.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use getServerSession() instead of getSession().